# Regarding Google Play registation

Tags: android, google-play

I have just registered with Google Play and paid my $25 and I was expecting a certificate or a registration number. I use http://appery.io to develop apps. What should I do next in order to obtain my certificate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as certification. Now that you paid the $25, you will get access to the Developer Console and will be able to upload apps to the Google Play store.

Comment: If I'm understanding what he's asking...I think he wants to know how to create the signed certificate involved in packaging the application into an APK file.

Comment: Oh, that might be the case. The question is very unclear though.